# Unicorn/Nginx deploy - no unicorn.sock is created (resulting in 502 error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, nginx, unicorn

My main problem is that I receive a 502 gateway error (the standard "something went wrong"-rails error, but console says it's 502) when trying to access my app.

Checking nginx error log reveals following:

```
2015/05/10 20:06:09 [crit] 32270#0: *10 connect() to unix:/var/sockets/unicorn.depot.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream
```

and indeed, there are no files in /var/sockets.

Initially I had my sockets path set to /tmp, but after reading, that files in the /tmp folder can be accessed only by services that created them I moved them into /var folder.

But there is more - the pid-file isn't created too.

Before I proceed with my config files - I have a strange feeling that this line in my unicorn_init.sh may cause the problem:

```
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
```

because when I execute it manually I receive following:

```
/home/deployer/apps/depot/current# bundle exec unicorn --restart
bundler: command not found: unicorn
```

However I'm afraid of installing unicorn on the vps via bundle install (unicorn is of course included in my Gemfile) as the shell tells me:

```
/home/deployer/apps/depot/current# bundle install  
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and 
installing your bundle as root will break this 
application for all non-root users on this machine.
```

I would appreciate any feedback, thanks in advance!

Here are my config files:

unicorn.rb

```
worker_processes 2
working_directory "/home/deployer/apps/depot/current"

# This loads the application in the master process before forking
# worker processes
# Read more about it here:
# http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html
preload_app true

timeout 30

# This is where we specify the socket.
# We will point the upstream Nginx module to this socket later on
listen "/var/sockets/unicorn.depot.sock", :backlog => 64

pid "/home/deployer/apps/depot/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

# Set the path of the log files inside the log folder of the testapp
stderr_path "/home/deployer/apps/depot/current/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "/home/deployer/apps/depot/current/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

before_fork do |server, worker|
# This option works in together with preload_app true setting
# What is does is prevent the master process from holding
# the database connection
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
# Here we are establishing the connection after forking worker
# processes
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream unicorn-depot {
    server unix:/var/sockets/unicorn.depot.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default deferred;
    # server_name example.com
    root /home/deployer/apps/depot/current/public;

    location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
    location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn-depot;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

unicorn_init.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Manage unicorn server
# Description:       Start, stop, restart unicorn server for a specific application.
### END INIT INFO
set -e

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/home/deployer/apps/depot/current
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
AS_USER=deployer
set -u

OLD_PIN="$PID.oldbin"

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_PIN && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PIN`
}

run () {
  if [ "$(id -un)" = "$AS_USER" ]; then
    eval $1
  else
    su -c "$1" - $AS_USER
  fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
  sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
stop)
  sig QUIT && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
force-stop)
  sig TERM && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
restart|reload)
  sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
upgrade)
  if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
  then
    n=$TIMEOUT
    while test -s $OLD_PIN && test $n -ge 0
    do
      printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
    done
    echo

    if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $OLD_PIN
    then
      echo >&2 "$OLD_PIN still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
      exit 1
    fi
    exit 0
  fi
  echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
reopen-logs)
  sig USR1
  ;;
*)
  echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: I have this problem too!

Comment: Did you resolve your issue? How?

Comment: @ryan2johnson9 Unfortunately - no. I switched completely to puma instead of unicorn using this awesome tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma

Works like a charm!

Comment: OK - this will be of no help to you but maybe someeone else one day then:
I got out of trouble by manually restarting my unicorn app after deployment. The Capistrano deploy used run `task :restart do
    invoke 'unicorn:legacy_restart'
  end`
but that did not seem to put the socket in the right place, but the manual restart from in server did with `bundle exec unicorn -D -c /home/deploy/apps/my_app/current/config/unicorn/staging.rb  -E staging`